# How to edit JSON Arrays?

Tags: arrays, json, key

I want to change all elements in the array, deleting keys I do not need and also turning  the names into keys for simplicity. How do you go about that?
Is there a simple piece of software or a website where you can edit JSON arrays in that manner?

What I mean is that I want to turn something like this:

```
"一": {
    "strokes": 1,
    "grade": 1,
    "freq": 2
},
"二": {
    "strokes": 2,
    "grade": 1,
    "freq": 9
}
```

Into something like this:

```
{
    "symbol":"一",
    "strokes": 1,
    "grade": 1
},
{
    "symbol": 二,
    "strokes": 2,
    "grade": 1
}
```

So yeah, what tool do you use to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking to *recommend* a tool, then the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

It can easily be done in one JavaScript statement though, so here's your tool:

```js
const json = {
  "一": {
      "strokes": 1,
      "grade": 1,
      "freq": 2
  },
  "二": {
      "strokes": 2,
      "grade": 1,
      "freq": 9
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(json).map(([symbol, { strokes, grade }]) =>
  ({ symbol, strokes, grade }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That works out for me. But where do I ask about any recommendations in the future?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/